# How to use jquery 'append' to add div after an 'focus'ed input, if there are more than one input with same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with inputs:

```
 <form action="xyz" name="form" id="fc" method="GET" style="background:none;display:block">
 <div class="a" id="a"> 
 <div class="b"> 
 <div class="c" id="c"> 
 <input class="input" type="text" name="name">
 </div>
 <div class="c"> 
 <input class="input" type="text" name="email">
 </div>
 <div class="c"> 
 <input class="input" type="text" name="sub">
 </div>
 <div class="c"> 
 <input class="input" type="text" name="web">
 </div>
 </div>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="su" value=""> 
 </div>  
 </form>
```

no, I want that when I focused on a input, than

```
 var appender = '<div class="nxt"><div class="btn" name="button" id="btn">A</div></div>';
```

added **after the div of this input**.

```
||---------------------|A| [ <div>||----------|</div> |a| ]
|----------------------|
|----------------------|
|----------------------|

|----------------------|
||---------------------|A|
|----------------------|
|----------------------|

|----------------------|
|----------------------|
||---------------------|A|
|----------------------|

|----------------------|
|----------------------|
|----------------------|
||---------------------|A|
```

currently I'm using this code :

```
 var any = {
 init: function(){
 var btn = $("#btn");
 var input = $('input');
 var appender = '<div class="nxt"><div class="btn" name="button" id="btn">A</div></div>';
input.focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().append(appender);
});
input.blur(function(){
    if(input.val().length == 0){
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".nxt").remove();
    }else{
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".nxt").css("display","block");
    }
});

btn.live("click",function(){
    input.val('');  
    btn.css("display","none");
}); 
 }
 }
 $(document).ready(any.init);
```

but this code will only append this 'appender' to the first input.

Can anyone provide me a good solution of it...

Comment: I always cringe a bit when I see chains of `.parent()` as this breaks so easily when you make tiny changes to the structure of your markup.
Have a look at `.closest()` which will give you a way to precisely hit the ancestor you're looking for through a selector you can specify. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var any = {
    init: function () {
        var $appender = $('<div class="nxt"><div class="btn" name="button" id="btn">A</div></div>');
        $('input').focus(function () {
            $appender.insertAfter($(this).parent());
        });
    }
}
$(document).ready(any.init);
```

DEMO: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/kDwb8/

Comment: thanks for this suggestion, but I want to append it after the input div, not inside their div.
like this:
<div>||---------|</div> |A|

Comment: Use insertAfter. I've edited the answer and the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/kDwb8/)

Answer (score 1):

Check this, let me know if i understood it right:

http://jsfiddle.net/6KZu8/

```
input.focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().append(appender);
});
```